# How to add popup in google vr view on the click of hotspot.

Tags: virtual-reality, google-vr

What I'm trying to do is, When I click on hotspot it should open a popup with little text. It is okay if the text is static, Is there any way we can make it possible? FYI I'm creating it for the web.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

I just started with google VR. I know it's a late reply but it is very possible.

```
function onVrViewLoad() {
    // init scene here and then:
    vrView.on('click', onHotspotClick)
}

function onHotspotClick(e) {

    console.log('onHotspotClick', e.id)
    triggerSidebar(e.id)

}

function triggerSidebar(id) {

    // add the class
    switch (id) {

        case 'item':
            document.querySelector('aside.item').classList.add('...')
            break
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, @meindent. I'll look into it and let you know if it is working or not for me.